# Suspected of hacking Windows 7 SP1

Tags: attacks

[image]

---

Hi.I have Microsoft Windows 7 SP1 on my PC. I have an Ubuntu OS near Windows OS. My internet connection has a proxy server from Iran that monitors our networking and filters some of our websites. These days I have used some software about free VPN, SSH+ and SSH that I think I have hacked from those softwares. (psiphon and freegate)

---

My antivirus software was Microsoft Security Essentials.

---

Windows default images in `Libraries\Pictures` have been changes to black image with some text on it:   File is encrypted. This file can be decrypted using the program *DirtyDesctype.exe*. Press CRTL+ALT+D to run *DirtyDesctype.exe* OR Check the paths (...).
I use all of the ways to run *DirtyDesctype.exe* but I cant find anything. I changed my antivirus from Microsoft Security Essentials to Avira but non can find any virus or unwanted program. Antiviruses reports sad that my system is **clean but it isn't**. (why?) I created another user on my PC and I have this problem on second user too.

---

My questions:

1. What is it?
2. Why I have this problem?
3. Where this come from? (My proxy server or those free VPN softwares or any where else)
4. How can I solve this?

Comment: This has a lot of questions, but the link Deer Hunter offered has all the relevant info for the first 4 questions. The 5th is off topic here.

Comment: Re #5, FWIW - [Product recommendations are off-topic throughtout Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). I.e. - the edit doesn't warrant reopening the question.

Comment: Mohammed - also, you don't need to make everything in your question a link. I have edited them all out except the image as they didn't help the question.

Comment: Just throwing it out there, Microsoft Security essentials is far from an Anti-Virus...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is a classic Ransomware.
2. You have been infected. How? there can be many answers.
3. It ould be any of the shady websites you visit ;) or a legit website that has been infected
4. I have mentioned the link below though I am not sure how effective it is as I have not been infected with this thing yet.
5. What do you mean by "managing internet usage"?

[Here's a Blogpost](http://virusremovalstation.blogspot.in/2013/07/infected-with-dirty-decryptexe-virus.html) on how to remove it:

> ## Step-by-step guides to uninstall Dirty Decrypt.exe Virus
>
> ### Manual Removal Guide:
>
> **Step 1:** Boot up the infected computer, press <kbd>F8</kbd> at the very beginning,
>   choose “Safe Mode with Networking” and press Enter to get in safe mode
>   with networking.
>
> **Step 2:** Press <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Del</kbd> keys together and stop Dirty Decrypt.exe Virus processes in the Windows Task Manager.
>
> **Step 4:** Search for all infected files and registry entries and remove them from your computer as follows:
>
> - %Temp%[RANDOM CHARACTERS].exe
> - C:\Documents and Settings\
> - C:\Users\< Current User >\AppData\
> - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System “DisableTaskMgr” = 0
> - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\random

Comment: monitoring downloads and uploads, servers that we connected to, unwanted popup pages, auto install softwares, auto run programs and ...

Comment: Buddy the thing is  , even if you monitor everything and your computer is running an older version of Java( just an example amongst many other softwares) you will still be hacked . It may not be Ransomware , it might be a exploit kit or something else .
For monitoring your network connection you can use "Netstat" amongst many other commercially available softwares . 
I personally use Mac as host machine and use XP\win 7 as a virtual machine with snapshot . 
Maybe a Windows user will be able explain to you better

Comment: This problem was from Torch browser that installs with iLivid.